# Find button's HWND in another application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to get HWND of button from Anchor Wallet application.
So far, I’ve written this code:

```
HWND window = FindWindow(0, L"Anchor Wallet (1.3.1)");
HWND class_ = FindWindowEx(window, 0, L"Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", 0);
HWND btn = FindWindowEx(class_, 0, 0, L"Home");

std::cout << btn;
```

The application window itself and the class of elements in this window I can find, but the button always has the address 00000000.

I tested UI with Inspect.exe. Here’s a screenshot:
[image]
Can you please tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Browsers don't use HWND-based controls, you have to use UI Automation to get to them.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050211-00/?p=36473

Comment: [The FindWindowEx function searches only direct child windows. It does not search other descendants.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa)

Comment: What is the screenshot supposed to demonstrate? It would certainly help if you provided one with English text.

Comment: You are using the Inspect tool for UI Automation, you are on the right the track. But you ask for finding button's `HWND`, wrong track. Use the spy++ tool (in Visual Studio's "tool" menu) to find application's `HWND`, then use UI Automation to find the button. Chrome can be tricky because it has a hidden window.